# Should a view flag be updated by API or the consumer?

Tags: rest, api, responsibility

I do hope this question is too subjective, as I am actually looking for a "best practice" that makes sense. However, the question is a bit more broad than just this case.

Lets say I have a view flag on an object (seen or not). When this object is seen, I see three options to make it true:

1. Let the app consumer set it by issuing an `UPDATE` call
2. When we call the `GetObject` method, we automatically set "seen" to true
3. We add a method in the API saying `SetToSeen` which the consumer is responsible to set

What is the favorable approach here?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

for me it depends *on who uses this flag*.

If it is the client, then the client should update the object (maybe "seen" could read as "displayed to the user") like `PUT /object/{id}/seen`.

If it this is only for the server and read as "displayed to the client", then the server should update if the object was served.